# angular material filter button always on the bottom right corner

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to implement a filter button on a result page like this one:
[image]

Is there any angular directive that implement this.

Like for example the snack bar that is positioned always on the bottom of the screen?

Comment: What have you tried yet? I would start with understanding the [position](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) property.

Answer (score 0):

Following CSS works fine.

```
.fab-button {
position: fixed;
bottom: 30px;
right: 50px;
}
```

If you're using angular material then the following can be added in the template HTML.

```
<button mat-fab color="primary" class="fab-button" aria-label="Add icon">
  <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
</button>
```